# SQL - pivot group element into new columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I got following query result at hand:

```
SELECT DISTINCT director, name
FROM Movie m
JOIN Rating ra ON m.mid = ra.mid
JOIN Reviewer re ON ra.rid = re.rid
WHERE director IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY director, name;
+------------------+------------------+
| director         | name             |
+------------------+------------------+
| James Cameron    | Elizabeth Thomas |
| James Cameron    | James Cameron    |
| Robert Wise      | Brittany Harris  |
| Robert Wise      | Chris Jackson    |
| Steven Spielberg | Ashley White     |
| Steven Spielberg | Brittany Harris  |
| Steven Spielberg | Chris Jackson    |
| Victor Fleming   | Mike Anderson    |
| Victor Fleming   | Sarah Martinez   |
+------------------+------------------+
```

Ultimately I want to obtain a pivot table, where all directors are one row and all matching reviewer names are in their own column. Just like this:

```
director         | name1            | name2           | name3
-----------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------+
James Cameron    | Elizabeth Thomas |James Cameron    | <null>
Steven Spielberg | Ashley White     | Brittany Harris | Chris Jackson
.......
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have built-in pivot functionality.  In addition, how do you know that there are exactly 3 reviewers?  SQL queries need to return a fixed number of columns.

Instead, you can put all the reviewers in a single list using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT m.director, GROUP_CONCAT(r.name SEPARATOR ', ') as reviewers
FROM Movie m JOIN
     Rating ra
     ON m.mid = ra.mid JOIN
     Reviewer re
     ON ra.rid = re.rid
WHERE director IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m.director
ORDER BY director;
```

If a reviewer could review a director more than once, then you want `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT m.director, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.name SEPARATOR ', ') as reviewers
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was fixated on obtaining all distinct reviewers per director in individual columns. I am coming from python/pandas and thought there was a dynamic way to pivot such a table.

Comment: Your answer absolutely nails it! I cannot accept yet though, SO wants me to wait a few minutes.